# Python - Plot Double Printing in Jupyter Notebook (When Using Statsmodel)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, statsmodels

I'm getting plots printing out in duplicate while using Jupyter Notebook.

This is specifically happening when using `statsmodels` plots.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to correct?

I googled around but didn't see anything.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the behavior of notebooks.

The workaround is to either assign the returned figure to some name or to end the line with a semi-colon.

details https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/1265